# Linking two Columns in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following columns in my table:

```
Title  |   Title Root
-------|--------------
A      |   null
B      |   A
C      |   D
D      |   null
E      |   null
F      |   E
```

I need to be able to have my query see that rows like B,C, and F have a value in Title_Root and display the corresponding title of that title_root. For example: B has Title_root = A. So then display the Title A. I don't want it to display B's title though.

I hope this makes sense. I just started doing queries.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I am using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple outer join:

```
select t1.title, 
       t2.title_root
from the_table t1
  left join the_table t2 on t2.title_root = t1.title
```

Or if you only want to see one title:

```
select coalesce(t2.title_root, t1.title) as title
from the_table t1
  left join the_table t2 on t2.title_root = t1.title
```

Comment: Do those queries only work if I am specifically telling the query that T1 = A and T2 = B? Or will that look to see if the row has a Title_Root and, if it does, display the Title_Root's corresponding Title?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple update statement should do the trick:

```
UPDATE Table
SET title = title_root
WHERE title_root is not null
```

Hope this helps.